# System error log

Tags: magento-1.9, log

When I see my system.log I see a error name :

> 2015-12-16T15:15:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): is_readable() expects parameter 1
>   to be a valid path, string
>   given/data/web/public/lib/Varien/Io/File.php

Does anyone know where this error comes from and what I can do about it?

When I go to the file `file.php`. I see the code:

```
protected function _checkSrcIsFile($src)
{
    $result = false;
    if (is_string($src) && is_readable($src) && is_file($src)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: The above answer is not clear at all because $src is being passed as an argument in the function so I don't understand where you gonna replace $src with ```Varien_Io_File::write()``` so this doesn't seem like a solution to this warning.
who got a solution for this problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153742)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153742)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153742)

Answer (score 5):

The log entry

> is_readable() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

occurs due to a bug in the Varien library. The method `Varien_Io_File::write()` can be used to either

1. write given data to a given destination file or
2. copy the contents from a given source file to a given destination file.

These use cases are distinguished by checking the second parameter `$src` of the aforementioned method via call to `Varien_Io_File::_checkSrcIsFile()`.

If `$src` turns out to be a filename, its contents are copied to the destination (use case 2). Otherwise it is interpreted as plain data (use case 1). The check applies [function.is-readable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) which always emits given warning in use case 1.

What you can do about it:

- Replace the initial call to `Varien_Io_File::write()`
- Fix the erroneous conditional switch
- Ignore the log entries

Comment: @Michel Van De Wiel I think this should be accepted as answer, don't you think?